# Need help to understand the Prove that the longest path problem is NP complete by reduction from Hamiltonian path

Tags: np, np-complete

Hamiltonian Path: If there is a path to visit each vertex of a graph exactly once.
Longest Path: Given a graph G=(V,E) and an integer k, decide if there is a simple path of length k.
In my class, the solution is to set k = V-1, and then it is trivial that the two problems are equivalent.
I can understand the direction from Hamiltonian Path to the longest path. But I cannot understand the direction from the longest path to the Hamiltonian path since the given number k does not need to be the number of vertices - 1.

Comment: Does this have something to do with a programming language?  If so, which one?

Comment: no, it is theory about NP-complete.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming.  May be suited to https://math.stackexchange.com/.